# How to authenticate mongo db using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

The Java MongoDB driver documentation says creating `mongoclient` will perform authentication, but it will never happened.

Here's my sample code:

```
new MongoClient(serverAddr, 
                Arrays.asList(credential), 
                new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                                     .socketKeepAlive(true)
                                     .socketTimeout(30000)
                                     .build());
```

Comment: Do you assign this to a `MongoDB` variable ?

Comment: Which type of authentication are you using?

Comment: I am using CR mechanism

Comment: Ideally MongoClient instantiation should authenticate the credentials. 
 For some reason, It is not happening.